# Adding with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections of `MontlySales` where each instance has three properties: `int Year, string Month and double Sales`.

I want to add these collections together so in the cases where both collections contain Sales for a certain month in a specific year their sales are added together and only represented with one node in the resulting collection.

### How would I do that?

Example:

Collection 1:

```
{2014,June,123},{2014,Aug,13},{2014,Dec,1}
```

Collection 2:

```
{2014,Aug,1},{2014,Dec,11}
```

Should be added together to:
Result:

```
{2014,June,123},{2014,Aug,14},{2014,Dec,11}
```

Comment: Post your code and your tests.

Comment: I don't have any code for this yet. Hence Im asking..

Comment: This site is for specific code problems, not to write code for you. Write some code to try some things first, and if you run into issues, then post your specific problems that you have issues with.

Comment: Did you build your class ? Did you try a basic 'foreach' loop ?

Comment: Hi Magnus, I think you haven't asked a "good question" - it's not clear what have you done -, what have you tried so far? The way your question is posted seems like you just want the answer and not the knoledge.

Comment: This is simple, I am posting as comment to help you get started. Do something like:
var CombinedList = list.Concat(list2).ToList();

Comment: I personally would use the following linq methods:  `GroupBy`, `Select`, `Sum`

Comment: Well I can iterate through the items with loops and add together but that would be dirty. Im thinking this could be solved with the Union operator or something like that?

Comment: "Im thinking this could be solved"
So try it !

Comment: Note, I cant just do a .Conact since that would result in duplicate months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
List<MontlySales> result = coll1.Concat(coll2)
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
                  .Select(x => new MonthlySales
                  {
                      Year = x.Key.Year,
                      Month = x.Key.Month,
                      Sales = x.Sum(z => z.Sales)
                  }).ToList();
```

**Update:**
Grouping and getting sum of sales, if `Sales` is `Dictionary<string,double>`, I have considered the following type based on your comments:-

```
public class MonthlySales
{
   public int Year { get; set; }
   public string Month { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, double> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Here, is the LINQ query to fetch the sales amount based on Year, Month & ProductName:-

```
List<MonthlySales> result = col1.Concat(col2)
     .SelectMany(x => x.Sales, (monthhlySalesObj, sale) => 
                  new { monthhlySalesObj.Year, monthhlySalesObj.Month, sale })
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month, ProductName = x.sale.Key })
     .Select(x => new MonthlySales
     {
        Year = x.Key.Year,
        Month = x.Key.Month,
        Sales = new Dictionary<string, double>{{x.Key.ProductName, x.Sum(z => z.sale.Value)}}
     }).ToList();
```

Please check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/73MTUN) where I have used this query with sample data.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! You are a star! If we took this one dimension further and had the sales being a Dictionary<string,double> of product names and their sales.

How would we then add them up so the resulting summarized nodes also have a total sales by product name?

Comment: @MagnusAhlin - You mean each MontlySales will have muliple sales? Since you are taking it as Dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Each instance of the class will have a dictionary of products and their sales. Im attempting with an Aggregate function to add them together but with no luck.

Comment: @MagnusAhlin - You want to add all sales under each product? I am not clear aboutt this.

Comment: Yes. So the Dictionary will have like different products sold and the total. But since we are adding together 2 collections of MontlySales in the initial question that you nicely solved for me(thanks again) the same product can appear in both collections for the same month and I want them added together. Lets say the collections represent what 2 different employees sold and I want to add them together so I see what is sold in total and its very likely they both sold the same products.

Comment: @MagnusAhlin - Okay got it! Let me give it a try :)

Comment: Awesome! Cheers! Let me know if you need a job :)

Comment: @MagnusAhlin - I am glad was able to help you. BTW enjoyed solving it :)

Comment: Seriously, if you are looking for a job send me an email. My address is in my profile. Or if you(or someone else know a good C# developer) get in touch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67936/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-magnus-ahlin).

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple:

```
// Combined two lists in a single list
var CombinedList = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Now use Linq `GroupBy` and `Select`:

```
var finalList = 
CombinedList
.GroupBy(s=>new{s.Year,s.Month})
.Select(x=>new
           {
             Year = x.Key.Year,
             Month = x.Key.Month,
             Sales = x.Sum(g => Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(g.Sales), 2)) // Decimal precision    
            }
).ToList();
```

Comment: @GreenChili The OP Also said that the reason why he can't use a concat is because it would result in duplicate monhts

Comment: @GreenChili - Nope! OP said he cant "just do a .Conact"